# What's the rules of placing parameter pack operator

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to understand how to use parameter pack in C++, and I came to some examples, what confused me is the placement of the pack operator`...`, sometimes it is before pack name, sometimes it is after:

```
template<typename... Ts> void func(Ts... args){
    const int size = sizeof...(args) + 2;  // <====== before
    int res[size] = {1,args...,2};   // <====== after
    // since initializer lists guarantee sequencing, this can be used to
    // call a function on each element of a pack, in order:
    int dummy[sizeof...(Ts)] = { (std::cout << args, 0)... };
}
```

Sometimes it is inside parenthesis, sometimes it is outside:

```
Class c1(&args...);
::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...) // <==== outside
```

Is there a general rule of pack usage?

Comment: Before when you declare it, after when you expand (use) it; the `sizeof...(Ts)` is a special case: it's just an operator to know the number of elements. When outside a parenthesis, expand the full content of the parenthesis.

Comment: How to read `{ (std::cout << args, 0)... };` or `U(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`? Why not `{ (std::cout << args..., 0) }` and `U(std::forward<Args>(args...))`?

Comment: The first one expand the content of the parenthesis; so become `{ (std::cout << arg0, 0), (std::cout << arg1, 0), (std::cout << arg2, 0),` etc. The second one expand the call to `std::forward()`, so become `U(std::forward<Arg0>(arg0), std::forward<Arg1>(arg1), std::forward<Arg2>(arg2),` etc.

Comment: Just like there's an `&` to indicate a bitwise and operation and an address-of operation, so does `...` is not the same thing everywhere. `sizeof...` is not a parameter pack that's attached to the `sizeof` operator. `sizeof...` is a single keyword/operator of its own. The whole thing, "sizeof..." gives you the size of the parameter pack that's specified, by name, inside the parenthesis.

Comment: With `{ (std::cout << args..., 0) }` you get `{ (std::cout << arg0, arg1, arg2, 0) }`. With `U(std::forward<Args>(args...))` is an error because you don't expand `Args` but, by example, `U(std::forward<int>(args...))` become `U(std::forward<int>(arg0, arg1, arg2))` (that is an error when `sizeof...(args) != 1` because `std::forward()` expect exactly one argument).

Comment: [Documentation of the syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: The page says "This section is incomplete"